# Нужно испортить и восстановить видеофайл?

Tags: binary, delphi, видео, предложения

Доброе время суток всем.  
Помогите начинающему "вирусописателю". :-)

Интересен такой вопросик:  
Можно ли с помощью обычного текстового редактора испортить обычный видеофайл (допустим, *.avi и другие типы) (например, дописать какой-нибудь текст в файл или еще как), так чтобы потом его можно было вернуть в первоначальный вид (т.е. сделать работоспособным)?

**Для реализации сего буду использовать Delphi.**

Заранее **спасибо**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не получиться сделать так быстро, т.к. в случае с xor-шифрованием потребуется каждый байт файла с помощью логического сложения по модулю складывать с какой-то строкой. Если понадобиться обратно его расшифровать, то нужно будет сделать тоже самое. Поэтому функция шифрования/дешифрования идентичны.

Вот самый простой вариант. В идеале нужно выносить в потоки, если полный файл собираетесь шифровать. Если нужно зашифровать N-байт, то нужно добавить счётчик в цикл.

http://pastebin.ru/Fxdqs1Jn

Answer (score 1):

текстовый редактор подавится бинарным файлом. А обратимо испортить легко – хоть реверснуть его, хоть за XOR'ить по ключу – да что угодно.

Если же вы хотите что-то умное сделать, типа, чтобы играла только первая секунда, а дальше облом – придётся разбираться во всех возможных контейнерах и кодеках – утонете..

Comment: А можно чуть-чуть поподробне, как реверснуть? (с ОДНИМ УСЛОВИЕМ - Эта процедура должна быть быстрая (файлы могут быть под 2Гб))
>т.е. нажал кнопку, реверс, запуск плеера, воспроизведение

Comment: Быстро... тогда бы я "бил" только самое начало файла. По аналогии с торрентами: иногда удаётся начать воспр. видео, если скачано самое начало файла и небольшой кусок где-нибудь в середине. Т.е. начало жизненно необходимо: там определяются формат, каналы, кодеки.

Бить - напр., просто инвертировать биты у первых N байтов.